# Unable to set 2 Properties using az functionapp plan update

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans

We need to set Property through az functionapp plan update

We are using Premium Plan.

The links

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-scale-per-app

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cli/azure/functionapp/plan?view=azure-cli-latest#az_functionapp_plan_update

does not talk about these 2 property accurate names...

per-site-scaling?
per_site_scaling?
perSiteScaling?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

per-site-scaling is a feature in app service not for the azure functions app.

[Maximum function app instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan?tabs=portal#maximum-function-app-instances)
In addition to the plan maximum instance count, you can configure a per-app maximum. The app maximum can be configured using the app scale limit.

In-order to increase the Maximum scale out limit of app scale out under a function app use the below command

```
 az resource update --resource-type Microsoft.Web/sites -g <RESOURCE_GROUP> -n <FUNCTION_APP-NAME>/config/web --set properties.functionAppScaleLimit=<SCALE_LIMIT>
```

Here is the more information about the [maximum scale out limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/event-driven-scaling#limit-scale-out) for app scale out in function app